# System.DllNotFoundException Raised when trying to run Microsoft SEAL in C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget, seal

I am currently working on a **Xamarin.Forms** based application that demonstrates the uses of *homomorphic encryption*. I followed the examples that were given on the **Github** page and I am now attempting to use this package myself. I installed the **Nuget** package to the project and wrote some basic code to use the SEAL functionality, however when I reach the second line of code,used to set the parameters of the encryption I get this problem.
This is the line I reach where it fails :

```cs
EncryptionParameters parms = new EncryptionParameters(SchemeType.BFV);
```

The error that is then thrown:

> System.DllNotFoundException Message=sealnetnative assembly: type: member:(null)

After researching I realizeed it has something to do with this **.dll** not being located by the project however I am struggling to fix this issue and I am in need of help!

Thanks in advance and I hope that I provided enough information.

Comment: from the README - "Currently the NuGet package is only supported in Windows."

Comment: I am using windows, Thanks!

Comment: "Xamarin.Forms" usually implies an iOS/Android project.  Or are you using it for just UWP?

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean it is only possible to use the nuget when developing for UWP? I had thought you meant I must be running Visual studio on the windows platform. I apologise for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I still am unsure as to what direction I should go in terms of installing SEAL to a new project. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jason I see nothing to that end in their README.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/master/dotnet/nuget/NUGET.md

Comment: Interesting, since https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL#from-nuget-package makes no mention of that. I wonder if the NuGet readme is referring to *building* the package?

Comment: The most confusing piece of this for me is the rest of the functionality of the package seems to be usable. When I remove the line shown above that sets the encryption parameters nothing else will cause the program to stop. I am very stuck on this issue and cannot find a solution!